# Automatic type conversion for user-defined Vector class?

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, destructor

I've overloaded the '+' operator for my `Vector` class as shown below.  Now, in the main program I use this operator in two cases:

1. The second argument to `operator+` is a `std::vector` instead of a `Vector` object.  I don't understanding why a the 2nd constructor is called or why the destructor is called, and it seems like the `std::vector` is being automatically converted to a `Vector` object.
2. The second argument to `operator+` is a `Vector` object.  I don't understand why the 2nd constructor is called.

Thanks.

Vector.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include <functional>  // plus
#include <algorithm>  // transform
#include <iterator>  // back_inserter

class Vector
{
private:
    std::vector<int> base;

public:
    Vector();  // dflt ctor
    Vector(const std::vector<int> vec);  // 2nd ctor
    Vector(const Vector& vec);  // copy ctor
    ~Vector();
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& rhs);
    Vector operator+(const Vector& rhs);
    void getBase();
};
```

Relevant definitions in Vector.cpp:

```
Vector::Vector(const std::vector<int> vec)
{
    std::cout << "2nd ctor \n";
    if(vec.empty())
    {
        base.push_back(0);
    }
    else
    {
        base = vec;
    }
}

Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& rhs)
{
    assert( base.size() == rhs.base.size() );

    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(base.size());
    std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(), rhs.base.begin(), std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<int>());

    return result;
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
    std::cout << "dtor \n";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Vector.h"

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int arr2[] = {10,20,30,40,50};

    std::vector<int> vec1 (arr1, arr1 + sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]));
    std::vector<int> vec2 (arr2, arr2 + sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]));

    Vector v1(vec1);
    Vector v2(vec2);

    std::cout << "\n Case 1: \n";
    Vector v3 = v1 + vec2;

    std::cout << "\n Case 2: \n";
    Vector v4 = v1 + v2;

    // program is paused here, so remaining destructors don't show in output
}
```

Output:

```
2nd ctor
2nd ctor

 Case 1:
2nd ctor
2nd ctor
dtor

 Case 2:
2nd ctor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me point out that there's a reason the standard library doesn't have an `operator+` for `vector`: It's *not* intuitive what it should do. Should it append the two vectors? Add the respective elements? Secret option 3? Even if it's "obvious" to you it won't be obvious to people who have to maintain your code in the future. A much better approach is simply named methods or free-functions.

That said, the reason you get the extra ctor2 and dtor calls in case 1 is because, first, your parameter is a `std::vector` but your operator requires a `Vector` so the only way to call the `+` is to convert the `std::vector` to a `Vector`. Then inside the operator you create a `std::vector` to populate with the result but the return type of the operator is `Vector` so again the result has to be converted in the `return` statement.

For case 2 you see the extra ctor2 for the exact same `return` reason as in case 1.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I was returning a std::vector.  So how does the program know to assign the vec2 std:vector to the Vector's base member?